# Text to speech - multiple calls

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I am writing a text to speech program. It works fine if its just one call that is made to the class, like so:

```
Text2Speech obj=new Text2Speech();
obj.dospeak("Hello this actually works","kevin16");
```

but when I try to use the same instance for another line, it gives an error:

```
Text2Speech obj=new Text2Speech();
obj.dospeak("Hello this actually works","kevin16");
obj.dospeak("second line", "kevin16");
```

> java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException>
>
> missing speech.properties in C:\Users\'user'

Even creating a new object still gives the same error. Again, it will work for the first call to the dospeak() method; it's the second line that wont be read out.

Here is the source code:

```
import javax.speech.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.speech.synthesis.*;

public class Text2Speech{
String speaktext;
public void dospeak(String speak,String  voicename)
{
    speaktext=speak;
    String voiceName = voicename;
    try
    {

        SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null,"general",  Locale.US,null,null);
        Synthesizer synthesizer =  Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
        synthesizer.allocate();
        desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc)  synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();
        Voice[] voices = desc.getVoices();
        Voice voice = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++)
        {
            if (voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName))
            {
                voice = voices[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
        synthesizer.resume();
        System.out.print("Speaking : "+speaktext);
        synthesizer.speakPlainText(speaktext, null);
        synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
        synthesizer.deallocate();
        System.setProperty("FreeTTSSynthEngineCentral", "com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
        System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
        Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String message = " missing speech.properties indf " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\n";
        System.out.println(""+e);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Text2Speech obj=new Text2Speech()
    obj.dospeak("Hello i am kevin ","kevin16");
    obj.dospeak("second line", "kevin16");
}
}
```

Comment: It's probably a mistake to assume that every possible exception is caused by a missing `speech.properties`... Does Java do stack traces? Does that tell you anything?

Comment: Ok, thanks.
From that the most helpful error trace was to the Java Thread class

"if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();"

is it maybe a threading issue???

Comment: It is better to use openmary, openmary voices are much better sounding too.

Comment: ok, thanks @NikolayShmyrev, I'll keep that in mind.
But the program is not fully functional yet, I still get an error when I try to run two calls to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of "dospeak".It works for me.:

```
 public void dospeak(String speak,String  voicename)
{
    speaktext=speak;
    String voiceName =voicename;

    try
    {   System.setProperty("FreeTTSSynthEngineCentral", "com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
        System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
        Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
        SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null,"general",  Locale.US,null,null);
        Synthesizer synthesizer =  Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
        EngineList engineList = Central.availableSynthesizers(desc);

        EngineCreate creator = (EngineCreate)engineList.get(0);

        List<Synthesizer> bagOfSynthesizers = new LinkedList<Synthesizer>();

        int numberSynthesizers=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberSynthesizers; i++) {
            synthesizer = (Synthesizer)creator.createEngine();
            bagOfSynthesizers.add(synthesizer);
            synthesizer.allocate();
            synthesizer.resume();
            desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc)  synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();
        }




        Voice[] voices = desc.getVoices();
        Voice voice = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++)
        {
            if (voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName))
            {
                voice = voices[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
        System.out.print("Speaking : "+speaktext);
        synthesizer.speakPlainText(speaktext, null);
        synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
        synthesizer.deallocate();


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String message = " missing speech.properties in " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\n";
        System.out.println(""+e);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```